# Emberjs: complicated routes (query params)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, ember.js, backbone-routing

Can I do a complicated route (query params) with emberjs?  I am still not sure if I want to go for emberjs as I have my app's routing established on backbonejs already. Just need to be sure before switching...

For instance if I use backbonejs,

```
routes: {
        ':module/:branch/:method?set=:setnumber&page=:pagenumber': 'renderPager'
        }

....

renderPager: function (module,branch,method,setnumber,pagenumber) {

            console.log("module => " + module);
            console.log("branch => " + branch);
            console.log("method => " + method);
            console.log("setnumber => " + setnumber);
            console.log("pagenumber => " + pagenumber);


        }
```

for a route like this,

```
#/media/image/list?set=1&page=3
```

then I get the answer,

```
module => media
branch => image
method => list
setnumber => 1
pagenumber => 3
```

I don't see any documents about such routing on [emberjs website](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/). and this is a warning page about [query params](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query params has just been rewritten and has just landed in canary (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4008). It will (probably) be in 1.4, however in my experience ember canary works mostly and if you don't mind a few bugs and a little bit of API churn it's great.